# How to check if a binary tree is complete

Tags: haskell

A binary tree is complete if the two sub-trees of every node are of equal size. Define a function that decides if a binary tree is complete.

I don't know how to write the next code, I think it is `Leaf a == Node a`, and then output a boolean value.
My Haskell code is show below:

```hs
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a [Tree a]

judcomplete :: Tree a -> Tree a -> Bool
judcomplete (Leaf x) (Node y (Leaf z)) = Leaf x == Node y (Leaf z)
```

Comment: A leaf, by definition, is never equal to a node. Using `Leaf x == Node y (Leaf z)` is pointless. If performance is not an issue, I'd start by coding `treeHeight :: Tree a -> Int` (by recursion) and `complete :: Tree a -> Bool` (by recursion, exploiting `treeHeight`). Note the single tree argument in `complete`.

Comment: The definition of the Tree is a general Tree and not a binary Tree. If this isn't on purpose, I would change the definition to a binary Tree as the question suggests. This would make the implementation more straight forward.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is a school assignment an very little effort is shown by the OP to solve the problem.

Comment: OP is a new contributor and may not know the rules. Advising them to show more effort first and then considering closing the question may be a better route to take.

Comment: The data type is somewhat redundant. At the term level, a `Leaf` and a `Node` are distinct, but `Leaf x` and `Node x []` are isomorphic for a given value `x`. `data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]` is sufficient for representing all non-empty trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is that for a tree to be complete every sub tree must be complete. We can think of a post-order depth first search where we check the condition of each sub tree and pass it to their parent.

The conditions we need to check are:

1. Are the number of nodes in both sub trees equal?
2. Has this been the case for the sub trees of the sub trees?

Note that we need 2 types of information from each sub tree, one is the number of nodes in that sub tree, in order to compare it with the number of nodes in the other sub tree, and the other is a bool flag that indicates how this test of equality was in the sub trees of that branch.

This leads to a recursive solution with the base case being a `Leaf`. A leaf has a straight forward answer: It is complete by definition and has 0 nodes. So, we could return `(True, 0)` from all `Leaf`s. None `Leaf` nodes do 2 things, compare the number of nodes in the left and right sub trees and also their bool values. If all these 3 conditions are true, they set the flag to true, otherwise false. They also add the number of nodes in the sub trees and increment them by one.

This leads to an `O(n)` solution where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree. I guess we can also implement it such that it lazily bails out of it finds a false along the way without diving down further recursive calls.

```hs
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)


judComplete :: Tree a -> Bool
judComplete x = fst $ go x where
  go (Leaf _) = (True, 0)
  go (Node _ left right) = (leftTrue &&
                            rightTrue &&
                            leftCount == rightCount,
                            1 + leftCount + rightCount) where
    (leftTrue, leftCount) = go left
    (rightTrue, rightCount) = go right
```

Comment: really, the levels approach best fits the problem IMO. it lets us do it without even counting. with depth-first you have to arrange for all kinds of information flows. it's bound to be non-trivial. (will read your post now...)

Comment: I think you are right about counting only the levels and comparing them is sufficient. Since we are comparing the levels of both branches at each node, I can't think of a counter example where this would result in wrong results. Counting nodes is extra information that is not necessary.

Comment: a. the levels approach will bail out the earliest. consider `Node very_big_complete_tree (Leaf _)`. b. the data type you're using is broken, can only house odd number of values.

Comment: hello @WillNess sorry if I did wrong with my reference to your solution. I didn't mean any harm. Anything wrong with my solution and its previous reference to yours has roots in my non-academic background and lack of experience both with Haskell and programming in general. Peace :-). Also feel free to correct/improve this if you see fit.

Comment: your solution is perfectly fine and you did nothing wrong.

Comment: thanks, much appreciate it :-) I'm here to learn from you guys and the answers I provide are beginner level for CS grads and mathematicians, I guess. Also, I just mentioned you here because I didn't know another way to tell you these. I'm going to remove these last 2 comments in a few mins.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you've understood my "levels" approach fully. it does not count anything, just goes level by level and detects whether there's a leaf among the nodes. `nextLevel lvl = [ t | Node lt rt <- lvl, t <- [lt, rt]]`. `hasLeaf lvl = not . null $ [ .... ]`. `hasNode lvl = .....`.

Comment: No, I did not. I was confused by the implementation, and back then I thought I understand the general idea of counting levels, but didn't see much of a benefit. But now that you mention it again as "it does not count anything, just goes level by level and detects whether there's a leaf among the nodes, I see where my misunderstanding was. For a binary tree (or any tree or rooted graph for that matter) to not be complete, there must exist a level where there is a mix of nodes and leafs (of any number). Or in other words, a leaf in any level except the deepest one.

Comment: yes, that's it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238192/discussion-between-user1984-and-will-ness).

Comment: You could return a `Maybe` instead of a pair. Dunno how that compares to what @WillNess wants to do.

Comment: I borrowed that tuple approach from Python. `Maybe` would be `Nothing` in case of a mismatch and `Just Int` otherwise, right? Wouldn't `Either` make more sense then? `Left _` when we already found a mismatch and `Right Int` otherwise. Will Ness's approach is fundamentally different. It doesn't keep track of counts. Just looks that in every level, all the elements have the same constructor (either a Leaf or a Node).

Comment: @dfeuer I've edited it [back in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69526590/849891) for the ease of access. It was always accessible trough the revisions list of course.

Comment: @user1984 [here it is](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/06b829d7ca1a86f1bb9f9fa7738072a7#file-so-69526590-complete-binary-tree-by-levels-md). but see [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/53254912#53254912) for more.

Comment: @user1984 I think you've described the `Maybe` approach pretty well. --- `Left _` what? `Left ()`? `Either () a` is the same as `Maybe a`.